# Pusher listener stop after some time

Tags: android, sockets, pusher

I'm using [pusher](https://pusher.com/) in my app to get some live values in-app from the server.

I'm subscribing to static channelName but somehow the user can't get data from the server if he keeps the app for a long time open, if the user restarts the app it works fine.

***in the pusher dashboard it works well and shows data go to users but, it's not.***

when I read on pusher I found that there is ping-pong but, even if I increased pong time it fails too

here is my code:

1- for pusher & channel create ( called in on create ):

```
options = new PusherOptions();

String APP_CLUSTER = "APP_CLUSTER ";
options.setCluster(APP_CLUSTER);

String APP_KEY = "APP_KEY ";
pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, options);

pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
        Log.e("PUSHER SUCCESS => ", change.getCurrentState().name());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
        Log.e("PUSHER FAILED => ", message);
    }
}, ConnectionState.ALL);
```

2- channel bind & subscribe ( called in onResume ):

```
 channel = pusher.subscribe("xxx");
        channel.bind("MessageCreated", event -> {
            Log.e("PUSHER DATA => ", event.getData());
        });
```

3- channel un-subscribe ( called in onPause):

```
pusher.unsubscribe("xxx");
```

4- disconnect pusher ( called in onDestroy ):

```
pusher.disconnect();
```

**I hope if anyone can give me the reason for disconnecting for some users, can someone tell me**

Comment: Increasing the pong timeout will mean the Pusher library will take longer to recognise a disconnection - it essentially gives the library a little more time to wait before determining the connection has been lost and therefore attempting reconnection. 
The debug console should show if the device loses connection (a disconnect and unsubscribe event will show). Does this happen in your case?

Comment: they stop receiving data after a long time idle, can I put a pong timeout to one day?